# Clone git repository from stash via HTTPS fails

Tags: git, https, bamboo, bitbucket-server

I'm trying to clone a git-repository from my stash-server via

```
 git clone https://admin@stash-url/path/to/repository.git
```

Unfortunately this gives me the following error

```
Cloning into 'repository'...
error: RPC failed; result=35, HTTP code = 0
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

When I try to clone via `http` it works just fine. I've tried finding some information about this, but I wasn't able to find anything useful. Does anybody have an idea, what I might be missing here?

Update: Cloning the repository on my windows machine with SourceTree works fine. That's bizarre, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stash developer here. That doesn't look good. We usually see problems like this due to proxy configuration. What are you using to provide the https - just Tomcat, or something like Apache?

You can try enabling debugging in Git/Curl to get more information:

```
export GIT_TRACE=1
export GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1
export GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1
git clone --debug https://admin@stash-url/path/to/repository.git
```

In any case I would contacting [Atlassian support](https://support.atlassian.com/), attaching the output from that command, so we can help you resolve the problem.

Cheers,
Charles

Comment: As far as I'm aware, it's an apache, but I'm not administrating the system, so I can's say that for sure :-/

Comment: Hi Vince. Sounds like your apache isn't configured correctly. Can you get your admins to contact Atlassian support with the above details?